# Vim: shiftwidth setting not reflected until i re-source vimrc

Tags: vim

I have the following setting  in my `~/.vimrc`

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

One running `:verbose set tabstop?` i get the output

```
  tabstop=4
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

But when i open any file, my indentation widths are always 2.
Then if i run `source ~/.vimrc`, the indentation widths become 4.
To show that there is a difference , below is an example file. First line was written as `<tab>a`. After sourcing vimrc, second line was written using `<tab>b`.

```
  a
    b
```

Why does this happen? Why isn't my shiftwidth setting 4 not being used initially?

Comment: Is anything else being loaded below this line that overrides it? The override could be in a block of code that is only run once (ie, guarded by an initialization variable or something). Just a guess.

Comment: But wouldnt that be displayed by :verbose set tabstop?

Comment: Have you checked that `<Tab>` is not mapped by one of your plugins and affecting this somehow? `:map <Tab>`

Comment: even then other indendation keymappings like `>` or `=%` are also working with `shiftwidth=2`

Comment: You ran `:verbose set tabstop?` *before* opening a file, not after, wasn't it? Could you try running it after opening the file? It is possible that a filetype script is overwriting tabstop (I would guess Python).

Comment: i ran it after opening a file.